# why python nose unittest teardown fixture failed

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose, fixture

I'm using [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) test framework. When running a test module, the teardown function defined in it failed. the error raised says the fixture is locked by another process. here is my test module, **test_my_module.py**:

```
... ...    
def teardown():
    if os.path.exists(test_output_dir):
        shutil.rmtree(test_output_dir)
... ...

@with_setup(init_test_db, destroy_test_db)
def test_foo1():
    eq_(foo1(),1)

@with_setup(init_test_db, destroy_test_db)
def test_foo2():
    eq_(foo2(),2)
... ...
```

There is a db(sqlite3) file in the **test_output_dir** which been used as fixture. Actually it is that db file that cannot be remove by the teardown, due to it be locked by other process. To my understand, a teardown will always run after all test functions finished running. So why does that happen ? why can those test functions still lock the db file? Is it a sqlite3 issue or it's some wrong in my test code?

Comment: could you provide more details of whats happening in your `init_test_db` , `destroy_test_db` and `fooN` functions?

Answer (score 0):

You could try explicitly closing the sqlite connection in the teardown before removing `test_output_dir`.

Comment: it doesnt work even explicitly closing the sqlite connection.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I did have the same issue in my c# unit tests.

I solved it by using calling SqliteConnection.ClearAllPools() before deleting the database file, so it is related to connection pooling.

Maybe there is an equivalent method in python? I really don't know.